# Is it possible to codesign osx application with custom certificate?

Tags: macos, code-signing, codesign

I have a certificate issued by https://www.starfieldtech.com/ - is it possible to use it to codesign my osx application? I successfully imported that certificate (.pem) to Keychain Access. But I do not know how to add to it corresponding privateKey.key file.
This is a 2048 bits sha256 certificate.

Comment: What's the point?  If you code-sign with a non-Apple certificate, it won't be recognized by Gatekeeper and other Apple technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Convert .pem certificate to .p12

`openssl pkcs12 -export -in <OrName>cert.pem -inkey <OrgName>Private.key -passout pass:<password> -out <OrgName>.p12 -name “MyOrg LLC”`

2. Import it into Keychain Access
3. Project settings -> General -> Uncheck “Automatically manage signing”
4. Project settings -> Build Settings -> Signning -> Code Signing Identity -> Select “MyOrg LLC” in Identities in Keychain
5. Project settings -> General should looks like:

Provisioning profile: “None”
                Team: “None”
 Signing Certificate: “MyOrg LLC”